# Solutions for $2^p+4y^2-2=(2y^2+y)\cdot s$

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that $$2^p+4y^2-2=(2y^2+y)\cdot s$$ has an infinite amount of solutions $s,p$ when a value for $y$ is given. If not, for which $y$ does there exist an infinite amount of solutions.
$s,p,y$ are positive integers.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1PyHQ.png) are the ordered pairs $(y,~p_\min),$ with $1\le y\le100$ and $0\le p_\min\le10^5.$

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. $2y+1=8a+5$ or $ 4b+3$

Answer (score 1):

Not true. For $y=4$, we have
$$2^p+62=36s,$$
i.e.$$2^{p-1}+31=18s$$
Since the RHS is even, we have to have $p-1=0$. Then, we have $32=18s$, but there is no such integer $s$.

Comment: Updated the question if you want to take another look